Avoid unchecked return code (sy-subrc) after open SQL?
At where condition I'm getting this error

avoid unchecked return code (sy-subrc) after open SQL

How to resolve that error?
If sy-subrc eq 0.
  Select * from zit_tab
  Into table @data(lt_tab)
  Where prop_name = @is_prop_input-key-name.
Else.
  Return.
Endif.


The answer is in the message: it seems obvious that you don't check sy-subrc after Open SQL. Could you clarify your question?

Well, it would help to use an if-else-statement as such and not pretend it's a try-catch or something.

You fix that code inspector warning by checking the value of sy-subrc after every SELECT:
  Select * from zit_tab
    Into table @data(lt_tab)
    Where prop_name = @is_prop_input-key-name.
  IF sy-subrc = 0.
    " Handle the case that there are no results
  ENDIF.

Or if there is really no reason in this particular situation to handle the case that there are no results for this database query, you can also shut the warning up with a magic comment, as mentioned in the answer by Sandra Rossi. That would look like this:
  Select * from zit_tab "#EC CI_SUBRC
    Into table @data(lt_tab)
    Where prop_name = @is_prop_input-key-name.


It's only a warning ("==> No Handling of SY-SUBRC After Reading Database Statement"):

The information says that the message may be suppressed by adding the pseudo-comment "#EC CI_SUBRC.
NB: here is a minimal reproducible example to get the message:

Create the program
Report.
Select *
  from T005
  Into table @data(lt_tab).


Use this check variant:


Run Code Inspector (SCI) on the program with the check variant above.



You can declare lt_tab before the statement, and use it instead of @data(...). This way it's safe to reference lt_tab[] after the statement, even if there are no rows in zit_tab.
With what you have, accessing lt_tab[] with an empty zit_tab will give you a runtime error, because lt_tab[] will not exist.
refresh lt_tab. "optional, so you know it will be empty if zit_tab has no rows

(... statements ...)

If sy-subrc eq 0.
  Select * from zit_tab
  Into table lt_tab
  Where prop_name = @is_prop_input-key-name.

  loop at lt_tab. "perfectly fine!
    (... statements ...)
  endloop.
Else.
  Return.
Endif.

